# How to convert XML nested structure to CSV using groovy

Tags: xml, csv, groovy

My input XML  structure

```
<Root>
<Header>
  <Name>Abc</Name>
  <HDR>2345</HDR>
</Header>
<Detail>
  <Count>2</count>
  <LSR>25</LSR>
</Detail>
<Trailer>
  <Date>222</Date>
  <year>2012</year>
</Trailer>
</Root>
```

My output csv should look like

```
Abc;2345
2;25
222;2012
```

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import groovy.xml.*;


def Message processData(Message message) {
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String;
    def ag = new xml2csv()
    message.setBody(ag.execute(body))
    return message
}

class xml2csv {
    def execute(ins) {
        //define writer
        def writer = new StringWriter()
        //parse input
        def parsedXml = new XmlParser().parseText(ins)
        
        def content = new XmlSlurper().parseText(ins)
        def header = content.Header.children().collect().join(',')
        def csv = content.Detail.Trailer.inject(header){ result, row ->
         [result, row.children().collect().join(',')].join("\n")
        }
        println csv.toString()
        
        return csv.toString()
    }
    
}
```

tried above code but not working as the output i required.

Answer (score 0):

@tim_yates: Thanks for making this question readable!

@Abbas: If you can rely on that fact that the data you want to extract is always on the second level of the XML-treestructure you could try something like this:

```
class xml2csv {
    def execute(ins) {
        new XmlSlurper().parseText(ins)
                .children()
                .collect { it.children().join(";") }
                .join("\n")
    }
}
```